# How do I shrink a list but guarantee it isn't empty?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

In [ScalaCheck](http://scalacheck.org), I have written a generator of non-empty lists of strings,

```
val nonEmptyListsOfString: Gen[List[String]] =
  Gen.nonEmptyListOf(Arbitrary.arbitrary[String])
```

And then, assume I wrote a property using `Prop.forAll`,

```
Prop.forAll(nonEmptyListsOfString) { strs: List[String] =>
  strs == Nil
}
```

This is just a simple example that is meant to fail, so that it can show how the shrinking is done by Scalacheck to find the smallest example.

However, the default shrinker in Scalacheck doesn't [respect the generator](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/129), and will still shrink to an empty string, ignoring the generator properties.

```
sbt> test
[info] ! Prop.isEmpty: Falsified after 1 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: List()
[info] > ARG_0_ORIGINAL: List("")
[info] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     example.Prop
```

Comment: Probably not what you need, but could you not use `NonEmptyList` from Cats? You get a generator for that and then, within your property, you call `toList` to use a `List` in the code you are testing?

Comment: As mentioned in my update to the answer, I was using cats just for simplicity, but that's not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, and re-using the example from the github issue you posted:

```
import cats.data.NonEmptyList
import org.scalacheck.{Arbitrary, Gen}
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks
class ScalaCheckTest extends FreeSpec with PropertyChecks with Matchers{
  "Test scalacheck (failing)" in {
    val gen: Gen[List[Int]] = for {
      n <- Gen.choose(1, 3)
      list <- Gen.listOfN(n, Gen.choose(0, 9))
    } yield list

    forAll(gen) { list =>
      list.nonEmpty shouldBe true
      if (list.sum < 18) throw new IllegalArgumentException("ups")
    }
  }

  "Test scalacheck" in {
    val gen1 = for{
      first <- Arbitrary.arbInt.arbitrary
      rest <- Gen.nonEmptyListOf(Arbitrary.arbInt.arbitrary)
    } yield {
      NonEmptyList(first, rest)
    }

    forAll(gen1) { list =>
      val normalList = list.toList
      normalList.nonEmpty shouldBe true
      if (normalList.sum < 18) throw new IllegalArgumentException("ups")
    }
  }
}
```

The first test does fail showing an empty list being used, but the second one does indeed throw the exception.

**UPDATE: Cats is obviously not really needed**, here I use a simple (and local) version of a non-empty list for the sake of this test.

```
"Test scalacheck 2" in {
    case class FakeNonEmptyList[A](first : A, tail : List[A]){
      def toList : List[A] = first :: tail
    }

    val gen1 = for{
      first <- Arbitrary.arbInt.arbitrary
      rest <- Gen.nonEmptyListOf(Arbitrary.arbInt.arbitrary)
    } yield {
      FakeNonEmptyList(first, rest)
    }

    forAll(gen1) { list =>
      val normalList = list.toList
      normalList.nonEmpty shouldBe true
      if (normalList.sum < 18) throw new IllegalArgumentException("ups")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to define your own `Shrink` class in ScalaCheck.  However, it is not common nor very easy to do.

### Overview

A `Shrink` requires defining an `implicit` definition in scope of your property test.  Then `Prop.forAll` will find your `Shrink` class if it is in scope and has the appropriate type signature for the value that failed a test.

Fundamentally, a `Shrink` instance is a function that converts the failing value, `x`, to a stream of "shrunken" values.  It's type signature is roughly:

```
trait Shrink[T] {
  def shrink(x: T): Stream[T]
}
```

You can define a `Shrink` with the companion object's `apply` method, which is roughly this:

```
object Shrink {
  def apply[T](s: T => Stream[T]): Shrink[T] = {
    new Shrink[T] {
      def shrink(x: T): Stream[T] = s(x)
    }
  }
}
```

### Example: Shrinking integers

If you know how to work with a `Stream` collection in Scala, then it's easy to define a shrinker for `Int` that shrinks by halving the value:

```
implicit val intShrinker: Shrink[Int] = Shrink {
  case 0 => Stream.empty
  case x => Stream.iterate(x / 2)(_ / 2).takeWhile(_ != 0) :+ 0
}
```

We want to avoid returning the original value to ScalaCheck, so that's why zero is a special case.

### Answer: Non-empty lists

In the case of a non-empty list of strings, you want to re-use the container shrinking of ScalaCheck, but avoid empty containers.  Unfortunately, that's not easy to do, but it is possible:

```
implicit def shrinkListString(implicit s: Shrink[String]): Shrink[List[String]] = Shrink {
  case Nil  => Stream.empty[List[String]]
  case strs => Shrink.shrink(strs)(Shrink.shrinkContainer).filter(!_.isEmpty)
}
```

Rather than writing a generic container shrinker that avoids empty containers, the one above is specific to `List[String]`.  It could probably be rewritten to `List[T]`.

The first pattern match against `Nil` is probably unnecessary.